# Why don't R data.frame's display dates?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

When I run:

```
time <- as.Date("2014-02-01")
#time <- as.Date("01.02.2014")
time # just checking...
df <- data.frame(Time = date())
df <- cbind(Time = as.Date(time))
df

[1,] 16102
```

How do I get a data.frame to hold and return a "Date" object?

Thanks for anything in advance! Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to get to in your example, but this should do it:

```
time <- as.Date("2014-02-01")
df <- data.frame(time = time)
class(df$time)

[1] "Date"
```

Edit:

If you want to add a new row to a data frame all you have to do is index to a new variable using `$`:

```
time2 <- as.Date("2014-09-18")
df$newtime <- time2
str(df)

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
$ time   : Date, format: "2014-02-01"
$ newtime: Date, format: "2014-09-18"
```

Comment: I am trying to add a row to a data.frame. I want to parse a row of data from a csv file and put it into a data.frame after I have done some date and time calculations.

Comment: @user1481614 - You should have stated that in the question in the first place.  Editing your question now makes other answers invalid and I won't be notified of your edit.

Comment: @ Richard Scriven - Thanks for your advice. I did, in other posts but I don't get the answers I need, so, I'm trying to break down the problem into separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is

> Your first data frame does return a date object in its first column.

```
> (df <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date()))
#         Date
# 1 2014-09-20
> class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"
> class(df$Date)
# [1] "Date"
```

But your second `df` (which I refer to as `cb`) is not a data frame, it's a matrix (see `?cbind`). A matrix can have only numeric or character elements in each column. Date objects are stored as numeric values, so the date is coerced to its stored value when you use `cbind` on it.

```
> mode(Sys.Date())
# [1] "numeric"
> (cb <- cbind(Date = Sys.Date()))
#       Date
# [1,] 16333
> class(cb)
# [1] "matrix"
> identical(c(cb), as.numeric(Sys.Date()))
# [1] TRUE
```

To make it look like a date when you call `cbind`, you can use `as.character`.  It will be coerced to character, but it will look like a date.

```
> (cb2 <- cbind(Date = as.character(Sys.Date())))
#      Date        
# [1,] "2014-09-20"
> class(cb2)
# [1] "matrix"
> identical(c(cb2), as.character(Sys.Date()))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm relatively new to R (as you can see). In your opinion, what is better, a data.frame or matrix if I wanted to parse a row of data (financial - numeric, datetime) from a csv file and put it into tabular storage after I have done some date and time calculations?

Comment: Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
01.01.2014 00:00:00.000,1205.393,1205.393,1205.393,1205.393,0.0000

Comment: @user1481614 If you're working with dates, I suggest a data frame.  You'll have less hassle with the date-time formats

Comment: Richard, Thank you! I'll take your advice.